# WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type UserService with qualifiers @Default at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject

Tags: java, dependency-injection, glassfish, cdi

I get an error while `@Inject`. I don't understand why.

My Application Server: GlassFish 4.1.2

The server gives an error when I `@Inject` my Class I created

```
java.io.IOException: com.sun.enterprise.admin.remote.RemoteFailureException: Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : CDI deployment failure:WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type UserService with qualifiers @Default at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private jobs.SignUpCDIB.userServiceat jobs.SignUpCDIB.userService(SignUpCDIB.java:0)
```

The server gives an error when I @Inject my Class I created

```
package jobs;

import services.UserService;
import javax.enterprise.context.ConversationScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Named
@ConversationScoped
public class SignUpCDIB implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject
    private UserService userService;
}
```

I'm trying to inject it to another class like:

```
package services;

import jobs.User;

public interface UserService {

    void save(User user);
}
```

UserService implement java class

```
package services;

import jobs.User;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService, Serializable {
    @Override
    public void save(User user) {

    }
}
```

Maven pom xml file

````
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>loginTutorials1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>```
````

Comment: Your dependency management is completely wrong. Start by creating a good pom for a java-ee project. Hint 'provided' is the key (word) here

Comment: Can you tell me where I did it wrong?

Comment: @ResulZOROĞLU can you try annotating the implementation of the service as `@Singleton`?

Comment: Which  import javax.ejb.Singleton, import javax.inject.Singleton; @akortex91

Comment: `javax.inject.Singleton`

Comment: [maven java-ee site:stackoverflow.com](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=maven+java-ee+site%3Astackoverflow.com)

Comment: When @Singleton was added, it made no errors. What is the reason ?, I have never received such an error in my previous projects. Is it about versions?

Comment: Please do not write if you will not give detailed answers! @Kukeltje

Comment: I point you to MULTIPLE detailed answers. Pick the one that suites you most. And the reason I do not give a direct answer is that I'm not sure if this misconfiguration is the cause of your problems (it might be, it might not be), but the pom is at least wrong. Goodluck with your endeavours (I mean this in a positive way) But I'll ignore you from now on and not point you to errors in your configuration. And if you have this pom from a tutorial, drop using it, it is bad then... Oh and the stacktrace contains more about the error. (there can be several types of unsatisfied dependencies). Cheers!

Comment: @zoroglu the reason why you had no errors was due to the fact that your service method was not annotated in a fashion that could make eligible for scanning from the DI container. Adding `singleton` denotes this and makes it eligible for injection. this was evident from the error message `Unsatisfied dependencies for type UserService with qualifiers @Default at injection point`

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you're getting this error is evident from the error message produced by the DI container. As you can see by this:

`Unsatisfied dependencies for type UserService with qualifiers @Default at injection point`

The container notifies you that there is no bean eligible for injection for the requested implementation (i.e `UserService` is this case).

Adding the `@Singleton` annotation makes this visible to the DI container and at the same time automatically eligible for injection.

The annotation in question work pretty much in the same way as the `@ConversationScoped` you have on your other class, albeit with a few differences in the scope of which the bean is available.

I suggest you do a good read up on how bean and DI is handled in general.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your answers.
In my previous projects, I was not getting an error without using @ Default and @ Singleton. Is there a problem in my pom.xml file, what's the difference? Now I still do not understand why he made a mistake.

Comment: It worked because I wrote @Singleton. But DI had worked flawlessly, with nothing in the Glassfish 4.1.1 version.  In the Project I developed a year ago, why I didn't write @ Singleton did not give an error. I'm curious about the Difference. What am I missing? If you want, I can share my previous project with no errors.

Comment: This could depend on several factors. The DI container being different or different version and so on. If my answer was helpful for you and resolved the problem, please go ahead upvote it and make it the suggested one.